# Each event hub partition key sending data to different containers inside blob via capture

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

Is there a way by which I can publish data to different containers via capture for different partition key?

I mean each event hub partition key should output its data to different containers via event hub capture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this as if you are pushing data to different partition via partition key, then each partition will send its data to different folders inside the blob which are numbered from 0-partition_count.

Note these folder will reside inside the same container of that blob in which event hub capture is pushing its data.